# Assist a rookie with Java heap application

Tags: java, heap

I have been struggling for the last 4 hours with this school assignment on heaps. I have a basic understanding of how they work, but for some reason I'm having difficulties on implementing the idea on this problem. I would really appreciate some feedback and tips, since this doesn't seem to be going anywhere on my own...

The problem is as follows: we have an array of "machines" that are represented by integers. The integer implies the amount of time it takes for the machine to manufacture a product. We are also given an integer that represents the number of products we want to manufacture. The assignment is to manufacture the given number of products as quickly as possible and return the amount of time that it takes.

So, for example: we have the machines [1, 2, 3, 4] and the number of products is 10. The answer should be 6, because:

- At time (0) we "start up the machines" (do nothing)
- At time (1) we get our first product from the machine 1
- At time (2) we get two products, from machines 1 and 2, so we now have 3 in total
- At time (3) we get two prodcuts, from machines 1 and 3, adding up to 5
- At time (4) we get three products, from machines 1, 2 and 4, adding up to 8 in total
- At time (5) we only get one product, from the machine 1, so we now have 9
- At time (6) we get our last product from machine 1, and return the current time which is 6

The number of machines and products is between 1..10^5. The integers in the array (the speeds of the machines) are between 1..10^9.

I have managed to work out a working code for the problem, but it doesn't pass all the tests because it's not fast enough. Now I have tried things to make it more efficient, but doing so I have only managed to break the whole thing or make it even slower. For example, I tried checking if a machines "speed" in the heap is larger than the currentTime and then ending the loop to save some time, but all that did was make another test time out (no idea why).

```
public static long shortestTime(int[] machines, int amount) {

    PriorityQueue<Machine> heap = new PriorityQueue<Machine>();
    for (int i = 0; i < machines.length; i++) {
        heap.add(new Machine(machines[i]));
    }

    int currentTime = 0;  //Indicates how many time units have been used so far

    int timeOfNextProduct = -1;  //Tells the time when the next product(s) will be ready

    int numberOfNextProducts = 0;  //Keeps count of how many products will be ready at the next possible time any product can be finished

    int products = 0;  //Keeps count of the total number of products manufactured

    while (products < amount) {

        //We raise the current time by one
        currentTime++;

        //We check the next possible time for a product to be ready
        if (timeOfNextProduct == -1) {
            ArrayList<Machine> polled = new ArrayList();
            int i = heap.size();
            for (int j = 0; j < i; j++) {
                if (j == 0) {
                    timeOfNextProduct = heap.peek().getManufactureSpeed() + currentTime - 1;
                }
                Machine machine = heap.poll();
                if (timeOfNextProduct % machine.getManufactureSpeed() == 0) {
                    numberOfNextProducts++;
                }
                polled.add(machine);
            }
            for (int j = 0; j < polled.size(); j++) {
                heap.add(polled.get(j));
            }
        }

        //If there are products ready at current time, we add them to the 
        //integer "products" and reset the value of "timeOfNextProduct"
        if (currentTime == timeOfNextProduct) {
            products += numberOfNextProducts;
            if (products >= amount) {
                return currentTime;
            }
            timeOfNextProduct = -1;
            numberOfNextProducts = 0;
        } else {
            //We jump straight to the next interesting time
            //(minus 1 since we add 1 to currentTime in the beginning of the loop
            currentTime = timeOfNextProduct - 1;
        }

    }

    return currentTime;

}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    System.out.println(shortestTime(new int[]{1, 2, 3, 4}, 10));  //Prints out 6
}
```

public class Machine implements Comparable {

```
private int manufactureSpeed;

public Machine(int manufactureSpeed) {
    this.manufactureSpeed = manufactureSpeed;
}

public int getManufactureSpeed() {
    return manufactureSpeed;
}

@Override
public int compareTo(Machine t) {
    if (this.manufactureSpeed < t.manufactureSpeed) {
        return -1;
    }
    return 1;
}
```

}

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow!. Please Read [here](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) on how to ask a good Question. Your post is a huge mix of code, and text, which no-one is ever gonna read. Try to keep the questions as short and to the point as possible to get faster help

Comment: You forgot to ask a question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The way you are using the priority queue is the root of your problem.

The whole point of using a Priority Queue here is to know when a machine is done producing.

So you should let the machine know when its done producing by giving it a sense of the time, and then make the compare function based on when machines will have produced something.

That way you can take out the machines that produced something this time from the front of the queue, and place them back in at the back.

Comment: I think I understand what you mean, I'll try to modify my solution accordingly. Very helpful advice, thank you!

Comment: You're welcome! If you feel like this is all the help you need here, you can accept the answer so that people searching for stuff to answer dont stumble upon it over and over :).